# Map Projection for globe

Tags: coordinate-system, globe

I'm new to QGIS, and I'm wanting to export a world map that I can then project onto a sphere in After Effects. I'm just wondering what kind of CRS projection I would need to make the 2D map in, so that it all lines up properly when projected onto a sphere.